# Hard to Diagnose Network Issue

Tags: wireless-networking, internet, home-networking, wifi-configuration

I have a router in my home which broadcasts a wifi network in my home which I use to connect to the internet. This router was supplied by the ISP from which I am getting my internet connection.

Sometimes, it behaves strangely and denies certain connections. This means that I am able to access certain websites but not others. Usually, some websites like facebook.com, google.com, youtube.com are accessible but some websites like github.com, piazza.com, quora.com are not.

This is not an issue I am facing with the browser alone. I ran some commands and they don’t help either. For example, I have tried running `ping` and `traceroute` and their output is not very helpful either.

This happens in a non-deterministic manner — I am not able to understand what triggers this. 60% of the time, my connection works fine but the other 40% it doesn’t.

This also does not happen to all my devices at once. Sometimes, some devices would run fine, some devices wouldn’t.

I have also tried doing the simple fixes: Restarting my laptop, disconnecting/reconnecitng from/to the network, but those didn’t help.

I have also tried renewing my DHCP lease when this happens. I have also tried running `sudo route -n flush`. These methods sometime work, sometime do not.

Because of the non-deterministic nature of this problem, I am finding it very hard to diagnose the issue. Please let me know if I should have attached the output of some command or added any aditional information.

Comment: Please add the results of some pings and traceroutes and advise if rebooting the router helps..  I suspect there are multiple issues here, likely including a crappy router and carrier grade NAT (with dual IPV4/6 stack)

Comment: I don't understand why you got all of the -1s.  I wish people would post a comment when they have a problem with a post.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas - Probably due to the lack of information

Comment: You are probably right Mr @Ramhound .. I still wish that people would comment so the OP can learn how things are done around here for the future. :)

Comment: If it’s about domains, it’s most likely about DNS. So please do provide output of `ping` when it’s not working and/or any browser error messages you see.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as only certain domains seem to time out, this looks like a typical DNS issue. You can verify this by doing an `nslookup` and checking whether you get a timely reply.

If nslookups are slow or fail, your ISPs DNS servers may be slow or your router may be misconfigured. Try to change your router configuration to use a different DNS server, like Google Public DNS (8.8.8.8) or Quad9 (9.9.9.9).

Answer (score -1):

Are you using any VPN like Nord Vpn or any others? this can create connection problems. It has happened to me. I just put the vpn on pause for an hour and then proceed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).